# Aggregating Count(*) of similar strings using regex/case

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working in Postgresql with a table containing data from Billboard charts over the years which ranks artists based on airplay. I want to tally the count for how many times an artist appears on the chart but I am having trouble with dealing with instances where an artist is featured in a song by another artist or has collaborated with another artist.

For example, I have counted the number of times "The Weeknd" has charted when appearing as a solo artist, but "The Weeknd Featuring Daft Punk" is treated as a distinct artist. Similarly, "The Weeknd & Ariana Grande" is also treated as a distinct artist. I would like for all instances of artists whose name contains "The Weeknd" to be aggregated under one entry such that any charting songs featuring/involving "The Weeknd" are counted towards his total. I suspect that using regex with a case statement would work here but I don't have much experience with regex and am a little confused by how I can implement it within this context.

Simplified version of my query provided below--This returns the count for the number of times an artist appears on the chart in a given year:

```
SELECT year, artist, COUNT(*) as artist_count
FROM billboard_chart
 GROUP BY year, artist
 ORDER BY year, artist_count DESC
```

Comment: This'll be extra hard for artists like `The The`

Comment: Have you thought about counting / grouping by the result of a like or regex match.

Comment: Are just looking to count how many time "The Weeknd" appears?

Comment: If you can somehow delimit the artists within the artist column, then you could temporarily store them as distinct rows within a subquery. Postgres regexp_split_to_table can do this, possible wrapped inside of a regexp_replace for further treatment. The problem, however, is delimiting your artists. Can you determine any delimiters such as "Featuring" or "&"? If you can create a list, then it would work.